# Auto reference and iterators

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

What happens if std::vector::begin() is called but the returned iterator is assigned to a reference? Why does it work and where is the iterator value stored?

```
std::vector<int> v;
auto a = v.begin(); //I assume iterator is stored on the stack in variable "a".
auto& b = v.begin(); //What happens here?
```

Comment: Why not trying out? (The compiler should yell at you)

Comment: @DieterLücking Microsoft's compiler will happily accept the error, treating it as if you'd written auto&& b

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This line

```
auto& b = v.begin();
```

is an error, because v.begin() returns a temporary, and you can't bind a temporary to a non-const reference.

Comment: This might compile on the Microsoft compiler because of their dangerous 'extensions' to c++.

Comment: @RichardHodges: Good point.  I've changed the wording from "compile error" to "error".

Comment: Yes, it works with the Microsoft compiler and creates the same assembly code as the correct line. Confusing. I would have preferred a compiler error.

Comment: @Tom microsoft's compilers are poison. If you're in a microsoft environment , always compile your code on gnu or clang - to be sure you're actually writing valid c++ code. Otherwise porting later will be a nightmare.

Answer (score 4):

Nowhere. You have a dangling reference. Don't do this.

Most compilers will reject this, though certain versions of Visual Studio will pretend that you wrote `const auto&` and extent the temporary's lifetime. Where that temporary is stored is irrelevant.